# pub/sub middleware with persistent storage

Tags: messaging, publish-subscribe, middleware, in-memory-database, distributed-system

I'm looking for middleware for a distributed real-time system. The requirements are very simple - publish/subscribe key-value store with persistent storage:

1. Publishers publish "data items" to topics which get distributed to subscribers to these topics. These data items do not need to be queued as only the latest version is relevant (think stock price). If there are no subscribers the data item should be persisted for later (see 2) - only latest version, no queuing.
2. Subscribers can come on-line at any time and they need to receive the latest version of the data item from the specified topic immediately and then receive updates as they happen.

Is there anything out there that naturally implements this pattern? Best I've seen so far is Redis but it requires two separate transactions on each side, write + publish on publisher (and subscribe + get on subscriber) which means it's not a fundamental use case and does not guarantee it won't miss updates happening between these two calls. One commercial product I know does this is Tibco ActiveSpaces but ideally looking for something open source and .NET or at least Windows-based.

Comment: Why it's so important to not store outdated values? A common queue pattern with fanout behaviour (1 queue per subscriber) would work fine if number of subscribers is limited.

Answer (score 0):

[OMG's Data Distribution Service for Real-Time Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_distribution_service) (DDS for short) is a standard with several implementations that can do what you are looking for.

The 'persisted data' that you are looking for can be achieved by using the correct Quality of Service setting called 'transient', 'transient_local' or 'persistent', depending on whether or not you want the lifecycle of the data to outlive the lifecycle of its source, or even the lifecycle of the whole system.

The 'last value' semantics is a common use-case and default behavior, although DDS can store more than just that, if needed.

For a longer introduction, check out [this video](http://vimeo.com/user14186439/review/57448029/6138f1e5c1).